# How to add index to python FAISS incrementally

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, bert-language-model, faiss

I am using Faiss to index my huge dataset embeddings, embedding generated from bert model. I want to add the embeddings incrementally, it is working fine if I only add it with faiss.IndexFlatL2 , but the problem is while saving it the size of it is too large.
So I tried with faiss.IndexIVFPQ, but it needs to train embeddings before I add the data, so I can not add it incrementally, I have to compute all embeddings first and then train and add it, it is having issue because all the data should be kept in RAM till I write it. Is there any way to do this incrementally.
Here is my code:

```
    # It is working fine when using with IndexFlatL2
    def __init__(self, sentences, model):
        self.sentences = sentences
        self.model = model
        self.index = faiss.IndexFlatL2(768)

    def process_sentences(self):
        result = self.model(self.sentences)
        self.sentence_ids = []
        self.token_ids = []
        self.all_tokens = []
        for i, (toks, embs) in enumerate(tqdm(result)):
            # initialize all_embeddings for every new sentence (INCREMENTALLY)
            all_embeddings = []
            for j, (tok, emb) in enumerate(zip(toks, embs)):
                self.sentence_ids.append(i)
                self.token_ids.append(j)
                self.all_tokens.append(tok)
                all_embeddings.append(emb)

            all_embeddings = np.stack(all_embeddings) # Add embeddings after every sentence
            self.index.add(all_embeddings)

        faiss.write_index(self.index, "faiss_Model")
```

ANd when using with IndexIVFPQ:

```
   def __init__(self, sentences, model):
       self.sentences = sentences
       self.model = model
       self.quantizer = faiss.IndexFlatL2(768)
       self.index = faiss.IndexIVFPQ(self.quantizer, 768, 1000, 16, 8)

   def process_sentences(self):
       result = self.model(self.sentences)
       self.sentence_ids = []
       self.token_ids = []
       self.all_tokens = []
       all_embeddings = []
       for i, (toks, embs) in enumerate(tqdm(result)):
           for j, (tok, emb) in enumerate(zip(toks, embs)):
               self.sentence_ids.append(i)
               self.token_ids.append(j)
               self.all_tokens.append(tok)
               all_embeddings.append(emb)

       all_embeddings = np.stack(all_embeddings)
       self.index.train(all_embeddings) # Train
       self.index.add(all_embeddings) # Add to index
       faiss.write_index(self.index, "faiss_Model_mini")
```

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from adding as many vectors as you can before hitting memory limits, training your index, then iteratively loading and adding the remaining vectors *without* training? I know ideally it would be better to train on the full dataset but I can't think of a way to load all and train on all if the system can't handle the size needed.

Comment: Does it affect the results, if I train as much data till the memory limit and after that add data without training? I am new to faiss!

Comment: Ideally you would train with the full dataset, but as with your case it's not always realistic - so try and train with a sample that is representative of the (expected) full dataset, then add your data after. The training aspect of PQ focuses on creating clusters (I wrote about it [here](https://www.pinecone.io/learn/product-quantization/)) and as long as your new vectors fall into these clusters nicely, there's no problem.

Comment: Ok thanks @JamesBriggs ! Also I want to know if I can train the dataset multiple times? So like I train it in batches, like 15k sentences train and add then another 15k sentences train and add and so on.. did it work or only one time training is needed?

Comment: I could be wrong but I believe training is a one time thing, to retrain an index you create a new index and train it - but that wouldn't help in your case

Comment: oh okay.. So can I train it one time with as much as data I can and then simply next time load the trained index using faiss.read_index(file) and add more indexes to it??